# Addressing issue with disappearing li elements in navbar (HTML, CSS, JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let menuBtn = document.querySelector("#menu-button");
  let menu = document.querySelector("#menu");
  let menuItems = menu.getElementsByTagName("li");

  menuBtn.addEventListener("click", e => {
    if (e.target.innerText === ("✕")) {
      e.target.innerText = "☰";
      [...menuItems].forEach(item => item.style.display = "none");
    } else if (e.target.innerText === "☰") {
      e.target.innerText = "✕";
      [...menuItems].forEach(item => item.style.display = "block");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
  header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

#menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#menu-button {
  display: none;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
  #menu {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  #menu li {
    padding: 1.5rem;
    display: none;
  }
  #menu-button {
    display: block;
    font-size: 3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <button id="menu-button">☰</button>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

It's a simple nav menu with desktop-first approach that uses `flexbox`.

1. Viewport is less than 1050px and therefore shows hamburger button
2. Hamburger button is clicked to show menu in dropdown form. Hamburger button changes to "X".
3. "X" is clicked. The JS code changes all `li` elements to `display: none`
4. PROBLEM: Viewport is increased beyond breakpoint of 1050px. Since `li` elements were changed to `display: none`, menu is not shown.

Would appreciate suggestions on how to address this.

Also, smaller but nagging issue.

1. Viewport is less than 1050px and therefore shows hamburger button
2. Hamburger button is clicked to show menu in dropdown form. Hamburger button changes to "X".
3. Viewport is increased beyond breakpoint of 1050p and then back below breakpoint. Since all `li` elements were set to `display: block` in JS code, the dropdown menu appears. I'd like to make it so that the hamburger icon appears whenever viewport size is decreased.

Thanks for all and any help!

Answer (score 2):

Add & remove CSS classes instead of setting the inline style. Doing this will give CSS more control. Inline styles can only be overwritten by using `!important` and that will make it even harder to overwrite.

Instead of showing and hiding every individual `<li>`, only hide the parent `<ul>`. That will also hide all the children inside of it.

The example below adds and removes an `active` class to the `#menu` element when clicking the menu button. This active class shows the `#menu` on mobile where it is hidden. On larger screens, `#menu` is always shown.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let menuBtn = document.querySelector("#menu-button");
  let menu = document.querySelector("#menu");

  // First question: 
  // Add a class instead of inline styles.
  menuBtn.addEventListener("click", e => {
    if (e.target.innerText === ("✕")) {
      e.target.innerText = "☰";
      menu.classList.remove('active');
    } else if (e.target.innerText === "☰") {
      e.target.innerText = "✕";
      menu.classList.add('active');
    }
  });
  
  // Second question:
  // Watch a media query, reset the button and hide the 
  // menu when changing from large to a small size.
  const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('screen and (max-width: 1050px)');
  mediaQuery.addEventListener('change', ({ matches }) => {
    if (!matches) return;
    menuBtn.innerText = "☰";
    menu.classList.remove('active');
  });
});
```

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

#menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#menu-button {
  display: none;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
  #menu {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  #menu.active {
    display: flex;
  }

  #menu li {
    padding: 1.5rem;
  }
  
  #menu-button {
    display: block;
    font-size: 3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
  }
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <button id="menu-button">☰</button>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful response! I am trying to make more of a conscious effort to make use of classes as much as possible rather than inline code, but I thought the benefit was just cleaner, more readable, more easily maintainable code. I wasn't even aware of `!important`. Any ideas on addressing my seconds question? Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure I understand the second question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: If you click on the hamburger button so that the menu elements show in vertical layout and then increase the viewport size, you see the menu elements appear in horizontal layout. That's fine. Now if you decrease the viewport size, the menu elements then appear in vertical layout. I'd like for the hamburger button to show rather than the menu elements. In other words, any time we hit the media query breakpoint for less than 1050px, I'd like for the hamburger button to show by default. Does that make sense?

Comment: I understand. I've modified the answer. The addition is the usage of `window.matchMedia` which returns a [`MediaQueryList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList). This list will fire an event any time the media query is a match or not. So when it is a match, it will reset the button and hide the menu.

Comment: Thanks so much. I would not have figured out that I should use `MediaQueryList` without your help.